# Editable text filed in UICollectionViewCell blocks didSelectItemAt from being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My `UICollectionViewCell` has a text field, when I click the cell it lets me edit the text field but the `didSelectItemAt` function of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` is not being called. How can I overcome this?

```
class LetterCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var singleLetterTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func textDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
        if ((singleLetterTextField.text?.count)! > 1) {
            singleLetterTextField.text = String((singleLetterTextField.text?.last)!)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the collectionView function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LetterCell", for: indexPath) as! LetterCell
    cell.singleLetterTextField.text = data[row][column]

    increaseRowColumn()

    return cell
}
```

And I already set the delegate and the data source to the controller.

Comment: Disable userInteraction of UITextField and set responder manually.

Comment: 1. Do you need your text field to be editable? 2. Did select will work outside of textfield. It is unlikely but if you wa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Considering you need your text field to be editable.
2. `didSelect` will work if cell is touched outside of textfield.
3. It is not unlikely so if you want to recognize `didSelect` along with editing, you will need to do the calculation in textField `didBeginEditing`. A basic hack will be to set index path's values as tag or other property of your `textfield`, in `cellForItemAt` (check eg.). You can create a custom text field as well.

Here is update to your `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LetterCell", for: indexPath) as! LetterCell
    cell.singleLetterTextField.text = data[row][column]

    cell.singleLetterTextField.tag = indexPath.row//then you can use this tag to form indexPath and with that you can retrieve cell (if it's still visible)

    increaseRowColumn()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What if I want to get events when the textField/cell is being touched? Since I want to change its color on selection and then on deselection.

Answer (score -1):

First

```
singleLetterTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Then in didSelectItemAt

```
cell.singleLetterTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I have to re-enable to text field before I set it to - becomeFirstResponder. If I won't the keyboard won't pop... Any idea how I can overcome this issue? Meaning to keep the textField disabled while allow the user to type in it